# Deallocate SWIG wrapped object once the python host object is dereferenced?

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection, swig, destruction

I tried swig wrap a C++ class like this:

```
class Test {
 public:
  Test()  {printf("Construct\n");}
  ~Test() {printf("Deconstruct\n");}
};
```

Suppose the swig wrapped module is `pytest`, I tried the following code:

```
x = dict(a=pytest.Test())
del x
```

I see the output "Construct", which is expected. However, sometimes I don't see the output "Deconstruct". I guess that it is because the object holding the `Test` C++ object is not deallocated when I deallocate the dictionary `x`. So I tried this:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

I still don't see "Deconstruct". I saw it when I exit the ipython shell. So my question is (1) how do I explicitly let python deallocate the swig wrapped C++ objects when they are not referenced any more; (2) Is there a way I can let python behave in a way that the swig wrapped objects are deallocated immediately once the host python objects are dereferenced?

EDIT:

The problems may be happening when I do the following:

```
x = dict(a=pytest.Test())
x
del x
```

The second command is issued when I was trying to inspect what `x` is. Then the object is referred to from the `Out` list in ipython.

So now my question is: is it guaranteed that `gc.collect()` will have all unreferenced variables deleted (i.e., their `__del__` are called)?

Comment: No matter what I do I can't reproduce the error here, at least not without retaining a reference elsewhere or hiding the destructor from SWIG (which in itself prints a warning at destruct time anyway).

Comment: Thank you for trying it. It happened only once for me. Maybe it is as you said the reference is retained elsewhere. If I just type `x = dict(a=pytest.Test())` then `del x`, do you know of any python mechanism which will refer to x['a'] somewhere? ps., I was using ipython for this test.

Comment: @Flexo: you are right, this may be because the object is referred to in `Out`. I updated the question.

Comment: If you do the same thing in regular python (i.e. no ipython) it works as you expected. I think your question is more about ipython workbooks than about SWIG. SWIG generated wrappers promise to manage the lifetime of the C++ objects  that are owned by Python correctly, (See docs on `%newobject` for how to tell SWIG it owns objects in less obvious cases). If you want to be sure the objects get released at an exact time I'd suggest implementing the context manager protocol in your exposed interfaces though, as that's what Python programmers expect.